# Implementing if let statement causes an error

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

I have codes like below

```
var currentDocumentPart: DocumentPart
var documentPartArray: [DocumentPart]
let currentDocumentPartIndex = documentPartArray.indexOf(currentDocumentPart)
let previousDocumentPart = documentPartArray[currentDocumentPartIndex! - 1]
```

I want to implement if let statement to check whether `previousDocumentPart` is empty, but it doesn't let me since `previousDocumentPart`'s type is not optional. How should I change? or is there other way to check if it is nil besides if let?

And due to my implementation in code it seems like it is hard to change the type of `currentDocumentPart` and `documentPartArray` to optional.

Comment: `if previousDocumentPart != nil {}`?

Comment: Using non-optional types the item at previous index could not be empty unless the object has a property to indicate 'empty` or the index is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `previousDocumentPart` is inferred from the value assigned to it which in this case is `DocumentPart` (not an optional, hence no `nil` value allowed).

If you want to be able to check for nil values change the definition of `documentPartArray` to :

```
var documentPartArray: [DocumentPart?]
```